# How to set the transparency color for Toolbar and Navigation bar using MonoTouch?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, xamarin.ios

How to set the transparency color for Toolbar and Navigation bar? I need to show background image on whole screen. But I can't give the transparency color for Toolbar and Navigation bar. I assigned `UIColor.Clear`. But no use. It is showing black color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better answer is hide the navigation bar or toolbar..

or

its strange requirement so. u hav to use custo navigationbar and custom buttons :)

Comment: I tried already. But I added some UIBarButtonItem's on Toolbar. That button's also hide while hiding the toolbar. And How to set the Background image on Navigation bar?

Comment: No use same as hidden component.

Answer (score 1):

For `UIToolBar` & `UINavigationBar`  Use the below property

```
@property(nonatomic,assign,getter=isTranslucent) BOOL translucent
```

Go to Apple Documentation

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html

**Here is some finding:**

**Define a category for UIToolbar for brining transparency:**

```
@implementation UIToolbar(Transparent) 
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // do nothing in here
}
@end
```

In the IB set the toolbar as Black Translucent and non opaque.

**Note that:** this would make all toolbars in your app transparent.

**For UINavigationBar:**

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (custom)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {}
@end

navgationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how to do with MonoTouch?